# Not getting notifications when my wife posts

Tags: facebook, notifications

My wife and I do not get notifications when the other one posts. We are set as close friends and 'see notifications'. Apart from my wife, there are many other friends I do not get notifications from.

Comment: Hi Paul, we're an independent website that answers questions about a wide variety of web applications and not affiliated with Facebook in any way.